# Prove that there doesn't exist a continuous map $p : [0, 1] \to \{0\} \cup (\frac{1}{n}, 1]$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, proof-explanation

---

> Prove that there doesn't exist a continuous map $p : [0, 1] \to \{0\} \cup (\frac{1}{n}, 1]$

*My Attempted Proof*

Fix $n > 0$. Recall that $p$ is continuous by definition if and only if $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $d(x, y) < \delta \implies d(p(x), p(y)) < \epsilon$

Let $\epsilon = d(\frac{1}{n}, p(x))$

---

Now this is where I got stuck in the proof, I'm trying to show that there doesn't exist a $\delta > 0$ for my choice of $\epsilon$, however for $\epsilon = d(\frac{1}{n}, p(x))$, there doesn't exist a $p(y) \in \{0\} \cup (\frac{1}{n}, 1]$ such that $d(p(x), p(y)) < \epsilon$. Thus there doesn't exist a $y \in [0, 1]$ such that $p(y) \in \{0\} \cup (\frac{1}{n}, 1]$.

But even with all those facts, I still haven't shown the nonexistence of a $\delta > 0$ that satisfies the implication for continuity. Am I tackling this problem in the wrong way?

If I am, I'm assuming I'm making an error with quantifiers in my proof somewhere.

Comment: I'm quite sure $p(x) = 0$ is continuous.

Comment: If your map is surjective, you can use the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want your continuous map to be surjective.  In that case, the key is that $[0,1]$ is connected, whereas $\{0\}\cup (\frac{1}{n},1]$ is not.  The image of a connected set under a continuous map is a connected set.  Therefore any surjective map $[0,1]\to \{0\}\cup (\frac{1}{n},1]$ cannot be continuous.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the fact that continuous images of compact subsets of metric spaces are compact. In particular, since $[0,1]$ is compact, had there been such an $f : [0,1] \to \{0\}\cup (\frac{1}{n},1]$ that is continuous, then
$f([0,1])$ would have been compact, which is a contradiction.

I am also inherently assuming that you persist your map to be surjective. Otherwise, just take $f(x) = 0$, for every $x \in [0,1]$. This map is clearly continuous, and satisfies your needs.